# Why do AlAs and GaAs have the same lattice constant?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Is it related to the electron affinity of the AlAs being larger than GaAs?

Answer (score 1):

Its because the covalent radii of Ga (122 pm) and Al (121 pm) are very similar.

Src: https://www.webelements.com/aluminium/atom_sizes.html

and

https://www.webelements.com/gallium/atom_sizes.html